# How to filter the error log writer: TLS handshake error

Tags: go

How to filter out these kind of error messages in the error log? These messages flood the error log and it's hard to monitor the application.

The messages mainly happens when something tries to make a TLS connection without any HTTP request

```
2022/10/23 01:05:26 server.go:3230: http: TLS handshake error from xx.xx.xx.xx: read tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:x->xx.xx.xx.xx: read: connection reset by peer
2022/10/23 01:05:26 server.go:3230: http: TLS handshake error from xx.xx.xx.xx: tls: client requested unsupported application protocols ([http/0.9 http/1.0 spdy/1 spdy/2 spdy/3 h2c hq])
2022/10/23 02:58:54 server.go:3230: http: TLS handshake error from xx.xx.xx.xx: EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.Server` has the field `ErrorLog`. You can replace its underlying writer with a custom writer that filters out strings containing "TLS handshake error"

Below is a simple example with two servers. One server listens  to the  port 8443 and uses the full log. The other  server uses the  filtering log and listens to the port 8444.

Client connects to the servers. The server with the full log prints `http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:xxxxx: remote error: tls: bad certificate`. The server with the filtering log pints nothing.

The example demonstrates the simplest filtering logger that filters away lines  with a fixed substring.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// Filters out lines that contain substring
type FilteringWriter struct {
    writer    io.Writer
    substring []byte
}

func (fw FilteringWriter) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if bytes.Index(b, fw.substring) > -1 {
        // Filter out the line that matches the pattern
        return len(b), nil
    }
    return fw.writer.Write(b)
}

func NewFilteringWriter(writer io.Writer, pattern string) FilteringWriter {
    return FilteringWriter{
        writer:    writer,
        substring: []byte(pattern),
    }
}

// Server handler function
func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("Hello, world!\n"))
}

// Trivial server executor
func runServer(server *http.Server, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    server.ListenAndServeTLS("server.crt", "server.key")
    wg.Done()
}

// Shutdown server
func shutdownServer(server *http.Server) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), time.Now().Add(2*time.Second))
    server.Shutdown(ctx)
    cancel()
}

func main() {
    fullLogger := log.New(
        os.Stderr,
        "full: ",
        log.LstdFlags,
    )
    // Log that filters "TLS handshake error"
    errorLogger := log.New(
        NewFilteringWriter(
            os.Stderr,
            "http: TLS handshake error",
        ),
        "filtered: ",
        log.LstdFlags,
    )

    serverMux := http.NewServeMux()
    serverMux.HandleFunc("/hello", HelloWorld)

    server1 := &http.Server{
        Addr:     "localhost:8443",
        Handler:  serverMux,
        ErrorLog: fullLogger,
    }
    server2 := &http.Server{
        Addr:     "localhost:8444",
        Handler:  serverMux,
        ErrorLog: errorLogger,
    }

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)
    go runServer(server1, &wg)
    go runServer(server2, &wg)

    // Test loggers
    // Client connects to the servers
    // The server with the full log prints
    // `http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:53182: remote error: tls: bad certificate`
    // the server with the filtering log pints nothing
    client := http.Client{}

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    log.Println("Client connects to the server with full log")
    reponse, err := client.Get(fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/hello", server1.Addr))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Client failed: %v", err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Server returned: %v", reponse)
    }

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    log.Println("Client connects to the server with filtered log")
    reponse, err = client.Get(fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/hello", server2.Addr))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Client failed: %v", err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Server returned: %v", reponse)
    }

    shutdownServer(server1)
    shutdownServer(server2)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Ouput:

```
2022/10/27 19:20:52 Client connects to the server with full log
2022/10/27 19:20:52 Client failed: Get "https://localhost:8443/hello": x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match localhost
full: 2022/10/27 19:20:52 http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:53182: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2022/10/27 19:20:52 Client connects to the server with filtered log
2022/10/27 19:20:52 Client failed: Get "https://localhost:8444/hello": x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match localhost
```

As you see there is the log line from the server 1 and no lines for the server 2.

Comment: @clarkk added full example with http server. In the  original post you asked about specific TLs logs, and the simple filtering  logger suppresses them efficiently. Regex support is possible, but it will lead to a higher overhead.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it possible to override the `ErrorLog` after the server is started? Your suggestion require a refactoring of my code

Comment: Or just override it before `http.ListenAndServeTLS()`

Comment: You can change it any time. Server logging function [uses `ErrorLog` field directly](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/net/http/server.go;l=3226). Any change change to it will take effect immediately.